# Find number of days Active days for account in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, gaps-and-islands, date-arithmetic

I am trying to find number of days to close account for particular account.

I have table like below:

```
OPER_DAY    |   CODE_FILIAL  |  SUM_IN         |      SALDO_OUT     |   ACC   
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-11-02  |   00690        |   0             |   1578509367.58    | 001
2020-11-03  |   00690        |   1578509367.58 |   9116497.5        | 001
2020-11-04  |   00690        |   9116497.5     |   0                | 001
2020-11-02  |   00690        |   0             |   157430882.96     | 101
2020-11-03  |   00690        |   157430882.96  |   0                | 101
2020-11-09  |   00690        |   0             |   500000           | 101
2020-11-19  |   00690        |   500000        |   0                | 101
```

Day starts with 0 sum and ends with 0 for particular **ACC**. I need to find number of days that filial had taken to close account.
For example for **ACC** 001 it took **2 days**, from 2020-11-02  -  2020-11-04. For 101 **ACC** it took 11 days. Because from 2020-11-02 - 2020-11-03  -> **1 day**,
from 2020-11-09  - 2020-11-19  -> **10 days**
Overall **13 days**.

Result I want:

```
----------------------------
CODE_FILIAL   | NUM_OF_DAYS
---------------------------
  00690       |  13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reads like a gaps-and-island problem. An island starts with a value of `0` in `sum_in`, and ends with a value of `0` in `saldo_out`.

Assuming there there always is at most one end for each start, you can use window functions and aggregation as follows:

```
select code_filial, sum(end_dt - start_dt) as num_of_days
from (
    select code_filial, acc, grp
        min(oper_day) as start_dt,
        max(case when saldo_out = 0 then oper_day end) as end_dt
    from (
        select t.*,
            sum(case when sum_in = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by code_filial, acc order by oper_day) as grp
        from mytable t
    ) t
    group by code_filial, acc, grp
) group by code_filial
```

This works by building groups of records with a window sum that increments every time a value of `0` is met in colum `sum_in` for a given `(code_filial, acc)` tuple. We can then use aggregation to compute the corresponding end date. The final step is to aggregate by `code_filial`.

Comment: Really good algorithm. Thank you very much!